# Turning off Reactivity during field edit

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a reactive form I am working on, and need to solve a problem.  The problem is that my users are using tablets/cellphones over slower cell connections, and sometimes loose connection.  When the connection is re-established, Meteor will fire off all the DDP messages, thus triggering Reactivity in the form, and thus overwriting any form input the user has performed but not saved.

So I came up with the idea of having temp values saved in the documents, so as the user changes the form inputs, the changes are stored in a "temp" value until they hit Save, at which time I simply copy the temp value over to the real value and blank it out.  Upon display I simply check if there is a temp value, and if so display that, and if not display the original saved value.

This works great for non-text fields like radio buttons and checkboxes, but it's not working well at all for text inputs.

The problem seems to be with reactivity.  As the user types, I have an even handler set on `change` and `keydown` (I also tried `keypress` and `keyup`) that simply fires off an update to the temp values like this:

```
'change .responseInput, keydown .responseInput': function(event, tmpl) {
  var response = Blaze.getData(tmpl.$('.headerDiv')[0]);
  var val = response.lastResponseValue;
  if (!val) {
    val = new ResponseValue({
      response_id: response.id
    });
  }
  val.tempValues = getSelectedValues(tmpl.$('div.responseDiv'));
  val.save();
}
```

In this event handler, `response.lastResponseValue` simply returns the last response value (I maintain history on the values the user inputs) and `getSelectedValues()` takes a DOM element representing the DIV around the form control and scrapes out the selected values, which might be a single String for a textbox/textarea, or an array of String values for checkboxes.  These pieces work as expected.

What doesn't work is the `val.save()`.  When selecting a Text input field and typing fast, the experience is that the typed text is randomly skipped/ignored/removed, most likely due to reactivity.  I tried wrapping the event handler in a `Tracker.nonreactive()` to turn off reactivity, but that doesn't seem to help.  I am guessing because it's not the `save()` that's reactive, but rather the `find()`.

I thought about separating the temp value stuff into a separate document.  Then the actual value wouldn't be touched, only the temp on attached to it, but I'd end up needed to write code that still returned the temp value, else the original problem would not be fixed at all, in which case I think I'd be right back in the same boat where there is a race condition between the user and reactivity.

Is there a way to temporarily turn off reactivity on a document in Meteor/Blaze?  Or is there simply a better method/pattern I could follow that would make this work better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form elements shouldn't be connected to any reactive values at all, otherwise they'll be wiped out just like you're seeing, and also during a hot code push.

Instead, you should initialise the form just once when the template is rendered. If the underlying values then change while the user is editing the form then the form won't be updated automatically, which is logical in most use cases.

You'll still need to update a local storage as the user makes changes though, so that you can put the form back to it's *edited* state if a hot code push occurs.

Take a look at this, it handles all that with ease:

http://viewmodel.meteor.com/

Tim

Comment: So, I have been reading up on the ViewModel.  I think that's exactly what I need.  The one hangup I have in swapping it in is I haven't figured out a way to handle the binding when the value can be an array of items, like when you have a bunch of checkboxes.  Their example for checkbox binding assumes one VM for each checkbox.

Comment: I missed the case of binding multiple checkboxes to an array. I will update ViewModel. It's an easy fix.